# How can i override custom html tag content?

Tags: html, tags

How can I override customized HTML tag content?

My custom tag contains only one content for `userinterface`

```
<p>beach</p>
```

Some more functionality

All are included in one custom tag `<sea>`

I want to implement `<sea></sea>`. But I want sunrise instead of beach.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide some examples of your code so we can better understand your problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Please provide more details in question, this increases the chances of receiving sufficient answers see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example